# How to render a table with two header use jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid

like this picture
the second header at fifth line.

[image]

if there is no api to use,any other method ?

Answer (score 0):

now ，I use jquery reedit table dom to attain this effect.

```
      gridComplete: function () {
            let tr3 = $("#jqGridList tbody tr:last")
            tr3.find('td:eq(2)').attr('colspan', 2)
            tr3.find('td:eq(4)').attr('colspan', 2)
            tr3.find('td:eq(6)').attr('colspan', 2)
            tr3.find('td:eq(3)').css('display', 'none')
            tr3.find('td:eq(5)').css('display', 'none')
            tr3.find('td:eq(7)').css('display', 'none')
            //  合并 轻度 。。。。
            let tr2 = $("#jqGridList tbody tr:eq(2)")
            let html = `<tr class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr"><td></td><td colspan=2 style="text-align:center;">轻度</td><td colspan=2 style="text-align:center;">中度</td><td colspan=2 style="text-align:center;">重度</td></tr>`
            tr2.after(html)


        }
```